# setting defined zoom range for google maps in android

Tags: android, google-maps

Is there a way how to define specific zoom range for a mapView that would restrict user from zooming out or zooming in outside of this range? For example zoom range <2.8> would restrict user from zooming in more that to level 8 or zooming out to zoom level less then 2. I was looking for some method like onZoom, but I can't find any such method

Answer (score 1):

Need to override draw method like this.

```
 @Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
    super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
    if (mapView.getZoomLevel() < 2)
        mapView.getController().setZoom(2);
}
```

The MapView allows you to set the zoom level. It ranges between 1 and 21.

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: what I want to do is to forbid the user to zoom too much or un-zoom too much. So it will not be possible to zoom more then to level X by pressing default zoom buttons.